# Jquery Hover acts weird when I leave mouse over element

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have the following html:

```
<div id="join-us-subheader-imgs">
    <div class="subheader-img-wrapper">
      <img src="/wp-content/themes/lib/join_us/join-us_1.png">
      <p class="img-quote">"This is a quote example. And there's more text here."</p>
    </div>
    <div class="subheader-img-wrapper">
      <img src="/wp-content/themes/lib/join_us/join-us_2.png">
      <p class="img-quote">"This is a quote example. And there's more text here."</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.subheader-img-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.subheader-img-wrapper img:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.img-quote {
    display: none;
    width: 125px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

aaand the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".subheader-img-wrapper").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('img:first').fadeOut("slow", function(){           
                $(this).parent().find('p:first').fadeIn("slow");
            });
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('p:first').fadeOut("slow", function() {            
                $(this).parent().find('img:first').fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }
    );
});
```

the thing is, when I keep the mouse over the first  it starts go in and out the hover function like if I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs because when `.fadeOut` functions ends, the element receive a mouseout event, triggering your other function..

Comment: Exactly, to fix this I'd recommend set the width and height of `.subheader-img-wrapper` via JavaScript (images width and height).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do 3 changes,

a. Instead of hover, you should implement mouseenter handler for `img` tag and mouseout handler for `p` tag

b. Change css of `.img-quote` `position: relative;`

c. Sequence `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` using callback method, so that the `img` and `p` tags are not shown at the same time.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/45VyB/1/)